# Flagging comment design/UI bug?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, design

was just about to flag a comment with the `"other"` field and the `textarea` seems to come up like this.

[image]

<sup>*[`Full Image`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HX8hf.png)*</sup>

Notice how it expands all the way to the right?

Tested on:

- Chrome

  - Version: `40.0.2214.94 m`
- Firefox

  - Version: `35.0.1`

So I guess my question is, is this an intended design, or is it a bug in the layout/browsers?

It seems it could be fixed by changing the width of this element:

```
.popup-flag-comment textarea[name="other-text"] {
    width: 277px; // was 294px before
}
```

Comment: Thanks @KevinBrown, It felt like I was missing a tag but just couldn't remember which one it was!

Comment: This should be fixed now. Thanks for the catch!